# Creating a node fitting the horizontal width of two other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the two PGF nodes foo and bar positioned in a row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I create a third node below those two nodes with the width of foo, bar and the node distance between them?
Is there a way to do this with the fit library or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Related: [TikZ: Make node height span several others](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124371)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `yshift` together with `fit` and `inner sep=0pt` to get a node of the same height and width as the other nodes, but shifted vertically. Note that the placement of the node text is different than in a normal node, so I would suggest you use the `label=center:<text>` option to place the text instead. As Martin points out, you should also set the `outer sep` of the nodes you're fitting around to `0pt`, as otherwise your new node will be too large by `\pgflinewidth`.

[image: tikz fit and shift]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
    \node [
        mynode,
        inner sep=0pt,
        yshift=-1cm,
        fit={(foo) (bar)},
        label=center:foobar] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Below is an approach to get the vertical spacing between the old nodes and the newly created one right. Using the `calc` library, you can shift the new node down by the height of the old nodes by using `($(foo.south) - (foo.north)$)` You can't directly read the value of `node distance`, so I've appended code to store the value in a new key that can be read in a `yshift`.

[image: fitted and automatically shifted node]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/node distance/.append code={
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/node distance value}{#1}
    }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0.2cm,
    mynode/.style={
        draw,
        outer sep=0pt
    }]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
    \node [
        mynode,
        inner sep=0pt,
        shift=($(foo.south)-(foo.north)$),
        yshift=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/node distance value},
        fit={(foo) (bar)},
        label=center:foobar] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

A different approach is using the `let` syntax to calculate the difference between `bar.east` and `foo.west`, and using that to set the `minimum width` of the new node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
    \path let
        \p1=(foo.west),
        \p2=(bar.east)
    in node [
        mynode,
        below=of foo.south west,
        anchor=north west,
        minimum width=\x2-\x1-\pgflinewidth
    ] {foobar};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The inner sep was what I didn't know about yet. If someone knew a way to calculate the yshift automatically I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: The `outer sep` of the first two nodes should also create issues. It places the anchors on the outside of the node border, not in the middle of it. This should cause the fitted node to be 2x`.5\pgflinewidth` wider.

Comment: @h0b0: I assume you want the same gap between the old and the new node as you have between the two old ones? I've edited my answer to show one possible way of doing this.

Comment: @Jake: I suffered from that dearly. The issue is also that you can't get the original `outer sep` of the referenced nodes afterwards.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for the edit, I remember this kind of calculation. Do you think one could construct something like a `\xcoordof` macro that would allow inline usage, avoiding the `let` command? If you like, I can open a separate question for this.

Comment: @user946850: Yeah, I think you should open a new question for this. There are a couple of questions on this site about calculating the distance between nodes, but I believe all of them require a separate calculation step and don't allow inline usage (I fear there will be expandability problems).

Comment: @Jake: Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63831/8057

Comment: It may be worth noting that scaling the overall picture breaks the third option. The `scope` gets the scale, but the calculated width is not.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

Without `fit` and `calc`

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

  \makeatletter  
  \tikzset{minimum dist/.style 2 args={%
    insert path={% 
      \pgfextra{% 
       \path (#1);
       \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya} 
        \path (#2);
       \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}   
       \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpoint{\xa}{\ya}}%
                     {\pgfpoint{\xb}{\yb}}%
       \pgf@xa=\pgf@x}
        },
    minimum width=\pgf@xa}
    } 

  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw}]
      \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
      \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
      \node [mynode,below= 1cm of foo.south west,
            anchor=west,
            minimum dist={foo.south west}{bar.north east} 
           ] {foobar}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Another variant with `fit`:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw}]
     \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
     \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
     \node [mynode,below=1cm of foo.south west,inner sep=0pt,
           anchor=west,
           fit={($(foo.south west)+(.5*\pgflinewidth,0)$) 
                             ($(bar.north east)-(.5*\pgflinewidth,0)$)},
           label=center:foobar] {}; 
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you fit using the anchor nodes, why not move the anchor nodes instead of `yshift`ing?

Comment: What is your idea? What you want to say by "moving" the anchor nodes ?

Comment: I mean adding a vertical shift to the nodes used for `fit` instead of yshift-ing the node.

Comment: Ah! Finally I understand your request (perhaps , I'm not sure) `below=1cm` for example. Personally I don't use positioning and I prefer yshift-ing ! because it's more easy to scale the picture.

Comment: Do you want to substitute the first solution with the two-argument variant from the linked question?

Comment: no problem, I updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

Another one with a `getdist=p1 and p2` syntax. It gets the left border of the first and right of the second. I'm not sure if this is simpler but slightly cleaner.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    getdist/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    getdistc={#1}{#2},minimum width=\mylength-\pgflinewidth
    },
getdistc/.code 2 args={
\pgfextra{
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{east}}
    \xdef\mylength{\the\pgf@x}
         }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ultra thick][draw] (f) {foo};
\node[draw,ultra thin] at (1cm,0.5cm) (b) {bar};

\node[anchor=west,getdist=f and b,draw] at ([yshift=-6mm]f.west) {foobar};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `.code 2 args` (fine idea !), you don't need `\pgfextra`.

Comment: @Altermundus Ah, that's from an earlier version where I did all of this inside a path. Indeed it's not needed.

Answer (score 5):

A variant using `fit` library but without `outer sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw,line width=2pt}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};

    \node[fit=(foo)(bar),yshift=-1cm,%
    line width=1pt, %
    inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, % -1/2 of current line width
    draw,label=center:foobar]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, which does not involve the `fit` library, but computes instead the required width of the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={rectangle,draw}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
    \path let \p1=($(foo.west)-(bar.east)$),
              \n1 = {veclen(\p1)-0.4pt}      % 0.4pt is the width of the border line
              in node[mynode, below=of foo.south west, anchor=north west,
                      minimum width=\n1] {foobar};
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the value of the border line width (0.4pt)?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that Jake's answer also containes this solution, but even better, because he uses \pgflinewidth instead of the hardcoded value 0.4pt. Shoud I retire my answer?

Comment: Indeed, but your code is shorter.