# Align both left and right edge of a rectangular node to given nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a node fitting the horizontal width of two other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/creating-a-node-fitting-the-horizontal-width-of-two-other-nodes)

I want to draw a `rectangle` node whose width is determined by the extent of two other nodes. I know there is `minimum width`, but I find the extraction of x coordinates rather difficult. Is there an easy way to achieve the desired result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a};
        \node[rectangle,draw,right=0.2cm of a] (b) {b};
        \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of a.south west,anchor=north west] (ab) {ab};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

How do I control the width of the "ab" node so that it is right-aligned with "b"?

(And, by the way, how do I control the height of the "a" node so that it matches the height of the "b" node? My workaround consists of using a `\phantom{b}` in such cases -- rather hackish...)

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23480/8057

Comment: Instead of `\phantom{b}` you should use `\vphantom{b}` as that won't effect horizontal spacing. Alternatively you could use a `\strut`.

Comment: @user946850: I've edited my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23480/8057 to also show an approach that calculates the necessary width first and then sets the new nodes `minimum width` to that value.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Could you please provide an example for `\strut`?

Comment: @user946850: See the difference between `\fbox{a\strut}\fbox{b\strut} \fbox{a\vphantom{b}}\fbox{b}`  There is also a `\mathstrut` for use in math mode.