# Compute the x distance between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

Is there a way to define a macro which would *evaluate to* the x part of the distance between two nodes? I know there are the point registers `\p` and the correspoding `\x` commands, but I find them rather cumbersome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\xdist}[2]{%
  % Should compute a parseable representation of the
  % x part of the distance between two nodes
  1cm
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
        \node[rectangle,draw,below right=0.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
        \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
              anchor=north east,
              minimum width=\xdist{b.east}{a.west}] (ab) {ab\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

In the above MWE, the `\xdist` command is supposed to compute the minimum width of the `ab` node, but the value is currently hard-coded.

I am looking for a better way of [Creating a node fitting the horizontal width of two other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23480/8057).

Comment: Related: [TikZ: Make node height span several others](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124371)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**new version**

The idea from percusse [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/creating-a-node-fitting-the-horizontal-width-of-two-other-nodes/63769#63769) can be applied in this case and the code is better.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \makeatletter  
 \tikzset{minimum dist/.code 2 args={%
      \path (#1);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya} 
       \path (#2);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}   
       \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpoint{\xa}{\ya}}%
                    {\pgfpoint{\xb}{\yb}}%
       \pgf@xa=\pgf@x}
    ,
   minimum width=\pgf@xa
   } 

 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below right=2.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
               anchor=north east,minimum dist={a.west}{b.east}] (ab) {ab\strut};   
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

A macro is not a function ( mathematical term). When yo use `minimum width` you need to give a length. I'm not a great (TeX)pert but I think it's difficult to make exactly what you want (call a macro and get only the length).

A possibility

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \makeatletter  
 \tikzset{minimum dist/.style n args={4}{%
   insert path={% 
     \pgfextra{%
       \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{#2}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{#3}{#4}}%
       \pgf@xa=\pgf@x}
       },
   minimum width=\pgf@xa}
  } 

 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below right=2.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
               anchor=north east,minimum dist={a}{west}{b}{east}] (ab) {ab\strut};   
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

**Update**

A variant to use 2 arguments only.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \makeatletter  
 \tikzset{minimum dist/.style 2 args={%
   insert path={% 
     \pgfextra{% 
      \path (#1);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya} 
       \path (#2);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}   
      \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpoint{\xa}{\ya}}%
                    {\pgfpoint{\xb}{\yb}}%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@x}
       },
   minimum width=\pgf@xa}
   } 

 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below right=2.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
               anchor=north east,minimum dist={a.west}{b.east}] (ab) {ab\strut};   
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to get the minimum height, the next code gives the two dimensions

```
\documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

 \makeatletter
 \newdimen\y@min@dim 
  \newdimen\x@min@dim  
 \tikzset{h minimum dist/.code 2 args={%
      \path (#1);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya} 
       \path (#2);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}   
       \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpoint{\xa}{\ya}}%
                    {\pgfpoint{\xb}{\yb}}%
       \y@min@dim=\pgf@y}
    ,
   minimum height=\y@min@dim
   } 
  \tikzset{w minimum dist/.code 2 args={%
       \path (#1);
       \pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya} 
        \path (#2);
       \pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}   
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpoint{\xa}{\ya}}%
                     {\pgfpoint{\xb}{\yb}}%
        \x@min@dim=\pgf@x}
     ,
    minimum width=\x@min@dim
    } 
    \makeatother

 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below right=2.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
         \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
               anchor=north east,
               w minimum dist={a.west}{b.east}] (hab) {h ab\strut}; 
        \node[rectangle,draw,right=0.2cm of b.south east,
              anchor=south west,
              h minimum dist={b.south}{a.north}
              ] (wab) {w ab\strut}; 

              \node[rectangle,draw=red, 
                    anchor=north west,
                    h minimum dist={b.south}{a.north},
                    w minimum dist={a.west}{b.east},
                    ] (test) at (a.north west) {test};  
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very beautiful solution.

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what the OP wants but my english is not good enough to explain the confusion between function and macro and I don't know if we can use a trick to find a workaround.

Comment: @Altermundus: No, the solution is indeed beautiful. Is there a way to reduce it to two parameters so that I can pass `a.west` and `b.east` straight away?

Comment: Yes it's possible. With TeX and the same method, it's possible to find the node  name  and the anchor from `a.west` and it's possible with TikZ. I updated my code with a TikZ approach.

Comment: @PolGab not so beautiful, `minimum dist/.code 2 args` is better

Comment: @AlainMatthes How one needs to change your approach to calculate the `minimum height`instead of `minimum width`? (I tried it by changing the name of the macro and changing the last line of your macro as following but failed: `\pgf@ya=\pgf@y}
       },
   minimum height=\pgf@ya}`)

Comment: @John I updated my answer for your request. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Sorry, not quite: I would like to use both, `w minimum dist` and `h minimum dist` for a `node` at the same time, e.g. ` \node[rectangle,draw,left=0.2cm of wab.south east,
              anchor=south west,w minimum dist={a.west}{b.east},h minimum dist={b.south}{a.north}] (test) {test}; ` Depending on the order of your `minimum dist`-macros, the node will eventually be as wide as `w minimum dist` or as high as `h minimum dist`.

Comment: @John Yes I updated my code to avoid this problem.

Comment: @John I've a tex's problem to avoid the use of `newdimen`. It would be better to avoid the creation of dimen .

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: Here is a better solution via `let` operation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
  \node[rectangle,draw,below right=0.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};

  \path let \p{1}=(a.west), \p{2}=(b.east), \n{x dist}={abs(\x{2}-\x{1})} in
  node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,anchor=north east,minimum width=\n{x dist}]
  (ab) {ab\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**First answer:** Here is your example modified to use `\setxveclength`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setxveclength[5]{% newmacro, node1, anchor1, node2, anchor2
  \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{#3}}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{#5}}
  \edef#1{\the\pgf@x}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,draw] (a) {a\strut};
        \node[rectangle,draw,below right=0.2cm of a] (b) {b\strut};
        \setxveclength{\mydist}{a}{west}{b}{east}
        \node[rectangle,draw,below=0.2cm of b.south east,
              anchor=north east,
              minimum width=\mydist] (ab) {ab\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but not quite what I was looking for. Is there a way to stick to the interface I am suggesting (two arguments, returning the length rather than setting a length with it)? And if not, why?

Comment: `\pgfpointdiff` is enough to get the `x`and `y` of  a vector.

Comment: @Altermundus Yes! I change my answer to use `\pgfpointdiff`.

Comment: A little shortcut is using `\edef#1{\the\pgf@x}` directly after `pgfpointdiff` but then we need to have `makeatletter ... makeatother` so not much of a shortcut :)

Comment: @percusse: it's a good shortcut. This avoids the use of two arbitrary macro names (`\xa` and `\ya`). So, a new edition...