# How to measure accurately the distance between TikZ nodes centers when using relative placement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to measure accurately the distance between TikZ nodes centers when using relative placement. My answer is around 1.55 cm but this is ballpark.
[image]

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]


\node[place] (centeral node) {};
\node[transition] (right node) [right=of centeral node] {};


\draw [|-|] (centeral node.center) -- ++(1.55,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can probably use the `let` path operation (sorry, commuting now, I can't try an answer). But this question smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-XY-problem)... For what do you need the distance?

Comment: Thanks. Knowing the distance, we can better design our figures comprising more complicated nodes.

Comment: Does this help: [Compute the x distance between two nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63867/)

Comment: Enable the `on grid` option from the `positioning` library (p.242, pgfmanual, v3.1.5.b) then use `right=2cm of centeral node` to put the center of your new node at exactly 2cm of `centeral node` center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I don't understand the question I decided to write two answers.

If questions is how to exactly place a node at a certain distance of another node, it's easy to do it if you know the angle from initial node or it's possible to decompose the distance in its horizontal+vertical movement.

As an example, in following code, `right node.center` is placed at exactly 1.55cm from `centeral node.center`. There is no need to measure the distance between them.

Also `another place.center` is placed at an exact distance of `right node.center` but following an 60 degrees angle. Again the distance is know.

But if the question is how to measure the distance between `centeral node.center` and `another place.center` which is unkonwn, then `calc` library can help. This is the third example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]


\node[place] (centeral node) {};
\node[transition] (right node) [right=1.55 of centeral node] {};
\draw [|-|] (centeral node.center) -- (right node.center);

\path (right node.center) --++(60:2.13) node[place] (another place) {};
\draw[|-|] (right node.center) -- ++(60:2.13);

\draw[latex-latex] let \p1 = ($(another place.center)-(centeral node.center)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (centeral node.center) --  node[above, sloped] {\n1} (another place.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is to measure the distance between the central node and the node on the right, using [right=of central node]. The 1.55 is my guess but not accurate.

Comment: @Aria The problem with `right=of central node` is that the `default` distance (usually 1cm) is measured between corresponding anchors, therefore if you don't know node's size, you don't know the distance between centers. In this case you can use `calc` library to measure it, like in my example. But you can add option `on grid` to force that distances are measured between nodes' centers. this way you don't need to measure anything.

Comment: @Aria Take a look at section 17.5.3 in tikz documentation and will understand my comments.

Answer (score 5):

- Distance between of your nodes is equal to default value `node distance` between right and left side borders of nodes, i.e. between `(centeral node.east)` and `(right node.west)`.
- For convenience of writing of the distance between their centers I increase this distance to `22mm`
- Distance is calculated on the similar way as in @Ignasi [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554564/how-to-measure-accurately-the-distance-between-tikz-nodes-centers-when-using-rel/554573#554573) (+1) with help of the `calc` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 22mm,
     place/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50,thick, fill=blue!20,
                     inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style = {draw, thick, fill=black!20,
                     inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}
                     ]
\node[place] (centeral node) {};
\node[transition] (right node) [right=of centeral node] {};
%
\draw[|-|]   
    let \p1 = ($(right node.center) - (centeral node.center)$) in
            (centeral node.center) %
    to ["\x1",
        "\pgfmathparse{scalar(\x1*0.35145980pt)} \pgfmathresult\,mm" '] % 1pt ~ 0.35145980mm
            (right node.center);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**;
Using default value for `node distance` which is 10mm (or 1 cm if you prefer), decreasing edge labels font size and and increasing its `inner sep` for better readable of measured values, adding 10mm long red line between nodes, to show default value of the `node distance`, and set `outer sep=0pt` that it not influence to nodes distance, the above MWE become:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     place/.style = {circle, draw=blue!50,thick, fill=blue!20,
                     inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style = {draw, thick, fill=black!20,
                     inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\tiny, inner sep=5pt}
                     ]
\node[place] (centeral node) {};
\node[transition] (right node) [right=of centeral node] {};
%
\draw[|-|]
    let \p1 = ($(right node.center) - (centeral node.center)$) in
            (centeral node.center) %
    to ["\x1",
        "\pgfmathparse{scalar(\x1*0.351459803pt)}\pgfmathresult\,mm" '] % 1pt = 0.35145980mm
            (right node.center);
\draw[red] (centeral node.east) -- ++ (10mm,0);% for show default distance between nodes
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It yields to:

[image]

Value 14,9998 mm ~ 15mm is equal to:

`<default node distance> + (1/2)<minimum size of left node (=3mm)>+ (1/2)<minimum size of right node (=2mm)>`

Comment: There is a calculation error since `1 mm` measures about `3 pt`.

Comment: @AndréC, you are right. I will correct answer accordingly asap

Comment: @ Zarko;  Thanks. In my code what is the default value of node distance? That is my question. I do not want to change the default to 22 mm.

Comment: @Aria, than remove code line `node distance = 22mm` from `tikzpicure` options.. However, in this case the number will overlap with nodes borders, so as I said in answer,  I  increase distance for convenience of number reading.

Comment: Thank you so much @ Zarko. Your answer and @Ignasi both address my question. Since Ignasi replied first I put his as the answer. But your answer also was right to the point. Sorry it is not possible to accept 2 answers. But Zarko I highly appreciate your great support.