# Join arrows and wide nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, charts

I want to create a flow chart with tikz that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------
|  wide node                  |
-------------------------------
            |
-------------------------------
|  wide node                  |
-------------------------------
            |
 -------------------------
 |         |              |
------   ------       ------
|sub1|   |sub2|       |sub3|
------   ------       ------
  |        |            |
  -----------------------
           |
-------------------------------
|  wide node                  |
-------------------------------
```

Looks like a pretty basic flow chart. I tried a lot of stuff to join the arrows and get the sub nodes as wide as the other nodes, but I could not get it to work, my current code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,
shapes.symbols,chains}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text width=8em,
 text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{dummyblock} = [rectangle]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.5cm]
\node [block] (A) {A};
\node [block,below of= A] (B) {B};
\node [dummyblock,below of=B] (BB) {};
\node [block, below of = BB] (D) {D};
\node [block, left of=D] (C) {C};
\node [block, right of=D] (E) {E};
\node [block, below of=D] (F) {F};
\path [line] (A.south) -| (B.north);
\path [line] (B.south) -| (BB.north);
\path [line] (BB.south) -| (C);
\path [line] (BB.south) -| (D);
\path [line] (BB.south) -| (E);
\path [line] (C.south) -| (F.north);
\path [line] (D.south) -| (F.north);
\path [line] (E.south) -| (F.north);
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Does someone have any clue on how to fix this... any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Put a dummy coordinate `\coordinate (fn) at [yshift=5mm]F.north);` and connect `C,D,E` to it with `|-` not with `-|`.

Comment: Thnx for the reply, how can I connect the lines to the coordinate? I tried the following code: \coordinate (fn at [yshift=5mm]F.north); after \node [block, below of=D] (F) {F}; However now \path [line] (C.south) |- (fn); generates and error...

Comment: Let me write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,
 fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text width=8em,
 text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{dummyblock} = [rectangle]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.5cm]
\node [block] (A) {A};
\node [block,below =of A] (B) {B};
\coordinate [below = of B] (BB) {};
\node [block, below = of BB] (D) {D};
\node [block, left  = of D] (C) {C};
\node [block, right = of D] (E) {E};
\coordinate[below = of D] (fn);
\node [block, below = of fn] (F) {F};
\path [line] (A) -- (B);
\draw (B) -- (BB);
\path [line] (BB) -| (C);
\path [line] (BB) -- (D);
\path [line] (BB) -| (E);
\draw (C) |- (fn);
\draw (D) |- (fn);
\draw (E) |- (fn);
\path[line] (fn) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnx! Ideally I would like to make the A,B and F blocks wider, i.e. as wide as CDE together. I'll try to combine this with other stuff on this forum, maybe I can get it to work..

Comment: @dikdirk There you go : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23480/3235

Comment: It almost works, only the arrows are not draw straigh for some reason... I have put my code below. Do you any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Percusse, thank you very much for all your help! I combined all the above in the final solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text width=8em,
text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
\node [block] (D) {D};
\node [block, left  = of D] (C) {C};
\node [block, right = of D] (E) {E};
\coordinate[below = of D] (FF);
\node [ block,  fit={(C) (D) (E)},label=center:F, below = of FF] (F) {};
\coordinate [above = of D] (BB) {};
\node [ block,  fit={(C) (D) (E)},label=center:B, above = of BB] (B) {};
\node [ block,  fit={(C) (D) (E)},label=center:A, above = of B] (A) {};
\path [line] (A) -- (B);
\draw (B) -- (BB);
\path [line] (BB) -| (C);
\path [line] (BB) -- (D);
\path [line] (BB) -| (E);
\draw (C) |- (FF);
\draw (D) |- (FF);
\draw (E) |- (FF);
\path[line] (FF) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way for some reason my linux texlive latex distribution gives errors with (my windows miktex distribution does not give an error):

```
\node [ block,  fit={(C) (D) (E)},label=center:A, above = of B] (A) {};
```

this can be resolved by replacing this line with

```
\node [ block,  fit={(C) (D) (E)}, above = of B] (A) {A};
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost works trough combining all above suggestions:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2cm,mynode/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw}]
    \node[mynode] (foo)                {foo};
    \node[mynode] (bar) [right=of foo] {bar};
    \node[mynode] (bar2) [right=of bar] {bar2};
    \coordinate[below = of bar] (cbar);
    \node [ mynode,
        inner sep=0pt,
        yshift=-1cm,
        fit={(foo) (bar) (bar2)},label=center:foobar
       ] (foobar) {};
  \draw (foo.south) |- (cbar);
  \draw (bar.south) |- (cbar);
  \draw (bar2.south) |- (cbar);
  \path[line] (cbar) -- (foobar.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only for some reason the arrows are not draw straight from the coordinate below three nodes to the wider node... does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Replace the last line with `\path[line] (cbar) -- (cbar |- foobar.north);`