# Change node distance using a macro and include a label to the background next to the nodes

Tags: fontsize, nodes, labels

---

the picture doesn't fit onto an A4 page.
So what I would like to change/add is:

- the node distance
- the font size
- a vertical text which groups nodes together
- a number infront of each node as the "step number"
- a bigger distance between the "groups"
- a better way to code maybe as a macro, so when I have to include a node I don't need to change all the numbers

---

This is how far I got but the distance between the first and second node is different to the rest. I also used in my original document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,openright]{mpreport}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
```

but for the picture I had to use `\"u` for ü and so on...

---

### Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,backgrounds,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [schritt/.style=            {draw, fill=gray!10,    text width=22em, minimum width=25em, minimum height=1.5em, drop shadow, rounded corners, font=\small},
     pfeil/.style=              {<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
     hintergrund/.style=    {draw, dashed, fill=gray!40,rounded corners}]

    \newcommand{\beschr}[1]{\hfill\textit{#1}};

        %   Bauteil einlegen
        \node   (1)         [schritt]                           {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteil}};          
        \node   (2)         [schritt]   [below=1]       {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (1);                                                                                                                
        \node   (3)         [schritt]   [below=2]       {Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteil}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (2);    
        %   Arbeitsstellung
        \node (4)           [schritt]   [below=3]       {MZ 12 V\beschr{Spanner Innenblech vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (3);
        \node (5)           [schritt]   [below=4]       {M1 \& M2 V\beschr{B\"ugel M1 \& M2 vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (4);
        \node (6)           [schritt]   [below=5]       {M3 \& M6 V\beschr{B\"ugel M3 \& M6 vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (5);
        \node (7)           [schritt]   [below=6]       {M4 \& M5 V\beschr{B\"ugel M4 \& M5 vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (6);
        \node (8)           [schritt]   [below=7]       {MZ 13 V\beschr{Klemmeinheit l\"osen}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (7);
        \node (9)           [schritt]   [below=8]       {MZ 14 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahme vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (8);
        \node (10)      [schritt]   [below=9]       {MZ 15-19 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahmen vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (9);
        \node (11)      [schritt]   [below=10]  {MZ 21-22 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (10);
        \node (12)      [schritt]   [below=11]  {MZ 23-24 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (11);
        \node (13)      [schritt]   [below=12]  {MZ 20 V\beschr{Sperrventil vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (12);

        %   Falzvorgang
        \node (14)      [schritt]   [below=13]  {M7 Pos 1\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Vorfalzposition}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (13);
        \node (15)      [schritt]   [below=14]  {M7 Pos 4\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Grundstellung}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (14);
        \node (16)      [schritt]   [below=15]  {MZ 25-30 V\beschr{Vorfalzantriebe vorw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (15);
        \node (17)      [schritt]   [below=16]  {M7 Pos 3\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Falzposition}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (16);

        %   Grundstellung
        \node (18)      [schritt]   [below=17]  {M7 Pos 4\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Grundstellung}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (17);
        \node (19)      [schritt]   [below=18]  {MZ 25-30 R\beschr{Vorfalzantriebe r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (18);
        \node (20)      [schritt]   [below=19]  {MZ 23-24 R\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (19);
        \node (21)      [schritt]   [below=20]  {MZ 21-22 R\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (20);
        \node (22)      [schritt]   [below=21]  {MZ 20 V\beschr{Sperrventil r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (21);
        \node (23)      [schritt]   [below=22]  {MZ 15-19 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahmen r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (22);
        \node (24)      [schritt]   [below=23]  {MZ 14 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahme r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (23);
        \node (25)      [schritt]   [below=24]  {MZ 13 V\beschr{Klemmeinheit r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (24);
        \node (26)      [schritt]   [below=25]  {M4 \& M5 V\beschr{B\"ugel M4 \& M5 r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (25);
        \node (27)      [schritt]   [below=26]  {M3 \& M6 V\beschr{B\"ugel M3 \& M6 r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (26);
        \node (28)      [schritt]   [below=27]  {M1 \& M2 V\beschr{B\"ugel M1 \& M2 r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (27);
        \node (29)      [schritt]   [below=28]  {MZ 12 V\beschr{Spanner Innenblech r\"uckw\"arts}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (28);

        %   Bauteilentnahme
        \node   (30)        [schritt]   [below=29]      {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteilentnahme}};
            edge                [pfeil]     (29);
        \node   (31)        [schritt]   [below=30]      {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}}
            edge                [pfeil]     (30);                                                                                                               
        \node   (32)        [schritt]   [below=31]      {Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteilentnahme}};

        %   Hintergrund
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node   [hintergrund, fit=(1)(2)(3), label={[rotate=90,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]left:Bauteil einlegen}] {};
            \node   [hintergrund, fit=(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(10)(11)(12)(13), label={[rotate=90,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]left:Falze in Arbeitsstellung}] {};
            \node   [hintergrund, fit=(14)(15)(16)(17), label={[rotate=90,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]left:Bauteil einlegen}] {};
            \node   [hintergrund, fit=(18)(19)(20)(21)(22)(23)(24)(25)(26)(27)(28)(29), label={[rotate=90,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]left:Falze in Grundstellung}] {};
            \node   [hintergrund, fit=(30)(31)(32), label={[rotate=90,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]left:Bauteilentnahme}] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Prozessablauf}
\label{abb:Prozessablauf}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: for `node distance` use `below=3mm of ...` (from `positioning` library which you already charged).

Comment: for `number in front` could use `\node[label=left:number] ...`

Comment: you don't need to `fit` all nodes, with upper and lower is enough. Instead of `fit=(4)(5)...(13)` use `fit=(4)(13)`.

Comment: You could consider to use several `matrix of nodes` one for group. Then you don't need `background nodes` because the matrix is already a node with its own border. Not the best example but you can look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102669/1952)

Comment: Thank you! I put the chart into a matrix as you sad. It worked out just fine but I have one more question regarding the nodes. You'll find it with this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121473/strech-the-text-to-the-borders-of-a-node-by-using-hfill).

Comment: I've added some comments to your new question regarding matrices. Hope they help to simplify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a partial answer following suggestions made in comments. I know Phil already followed and improved them (look at [Strech the text to the borders of a node by using \hfill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121473/strech-the-text-to-the-borders-of-a-node-by-using-hfill)) but this way some work for `answer the unanswered` session could be avoid ;-)

I think `node distance`, `a bigger distance between the "groups"`, `a better way to code`
can be solved organizing the diagram with several `matrix of nodes`. Within them `row sep` will fix `node distance`, and `positioning` library will help to place `every matrix` as far as we want fro  maybe as a macro

the node distance
the font size
a vertical text which groups nodes together
a number infront of each node as the "step number"

, so when I have to include a node I don't need to change all the numbers

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning, shadows,arrows,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [schritt/.style= {draw, solid, fill=gray!10, text width=22em, minimum width=25em, minimum height=1.5em, drop shadow, rounded corners, font=\small},
     pfeil/.style= {->,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
     hintergrund/.style= {draw, dashed, fill=gray!40,rounded corners},
     every matrix/.style={matrix of nodes, row sep=3mm, outer sep=0pt, hintergrund, nodes={schritt}}]

    \newcommand{\beschr}[1]{\hfill\textit{#1}};

        %   Bauteil einlegen
    \matrix (A) {
        {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteil}}\\
        {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}}\\            
        {Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteil}}\\};

        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] in {2, 3}
        \draw[pfeil] (A-\j-1)--(A-\i-1);

        %   Arbeitsstellung
    \matrix (B) [below=5mm of A.south]{
        {MZ 12 V\beschr{Spanner Innenblech vorw\"arts}}\\
        {M1 \& M2 V\beschr{B\"ugel M1 \& M2 vorw\"arts}}\\
        {M3 \& M6 V\beschr{B\"ugel M3 \& M6 vorw\"arts}}\\
        {M4 \& M5 V\beschr{B\"ugel M4 \& M5 vorw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 13 V\beschr{Klemmeinheit l\"osen}}\\
        {MZ 14 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahme vorw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 15-19 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahmen vorw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 21-22 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 23-24 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 20 V\beschr{Sperrventil vorw\"arts}}\\};

        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] in {2, ..., 10}
        \draw[pfeil] (B-\j-1)--(B-\i-1);


%   Falzvorgang
    \matrix (C) [below=5mm of B.south]{
        {M7 Pos 1\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Vorfalzposition}}\\
        {M7 Pos 4\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Grundstellung}}\\
        {MZ 25-30 V\beschr{Vorfalzantriebe vorw\"arts}}\\
        {M7 Pos 3\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Falzposition}}\\};

        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] in {2, ..., 4}
        \draw[pfeil] (C-\j-1)--(C-\i-1);

        %   Grundstellung
    \matrix (D) [right=10mm of A.north east, matrix anchor=north west]{
        {M7 Pos 4\beschr{Hauptantrieb zur Grundstellung}}\\
        {MZ 25-30 R\beschr{Vorfalzantriebe r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 23-24 R\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 21-22 R\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 20 V\beschr{Sperrventil r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 15-19 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahmen r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 14 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahme r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 13 V\beschr{Klemmeinheit r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {M4 \& M5 V\beschr{B\"ugel M4 \& M5 r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {M3 \& M6 V\beschr{B\"ugel M3 \& M6 r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {M1 \& M2 V\beschr{B\"ugel M1 \& M2 r\"uckw\"arts}}\\
        {MZ 12 V\beschr{Spanner Innenblech r\"uckw\"arts}}\\};
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] in {2, ..., 12}
        \draw[pfeil] (D-\j-1)--(D-\i-1);


        %   Bauteilentnahme
    \matrix (E) [below=5mm of D.south]{
        {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteilentnahme}}\\
        {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}}\\
        {Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteilentnahme}}\\};
          \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially 1)] in {2, ..., 3}
        \draw[pfeil] (E-\j-1)--(E-\i-1);

\draw[pfeil] (A-3-1)--(B-1-1);
\draw[pfeil] (B-10-1)--(C-1-1);
\draw[pfeil] (C-4-1)--([yshift=-5mm]C.south)-| ([shift={(-5mm,5mm)}]D.north west) -| (D-1-1);
\draw[pfeil] (D-12-1)--(E-1-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Prozessablauf}
\label{abb:Prozessablauf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]