# Strech the text to the borders of a node by using \hfill

Tags: nodes, matrices

The text inside the nodes is not streched to the right side of the node by using `\hfill`.
Could it be the reason that it doesn't work with `font=\tiny`? But I need the text that small and I would like that the explanation text is at the right side inside the node and the short term like `Frg 1` is on the left side inside the node.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]

\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\tiny,
 pfeil/.style                   ={draw,->,shorten <=0pt,>=stealth', thick, -latex',shorten >=0pt},
 stext/.style                   ={draw,solid, fill=gray!10, text width=25em,minimum height=1em, drop shadow, rounded corners},
 snr/.style                     ={drop shadow,fill=gray!10,draw,solid,circle,minimum width=4mm,inner sep=0pt},
 every matrix/.style    ={matrix of nodes, row sep=1mm, column sep=3mm,fill=gray!40,draw=black,dashed,rounded corners,inner sep=2mm}]

    \newcommand{\beschr}[1]{\hfill\textit{#1}};

    \matrix (einlegen)      
        {
            \node   (e11)       {}; &   \node   (e12)       [snr]   {1.};   &   \node   (e13)       [stext] {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteil}};                  \\
            \node   (e21)       {}; &   \node   (e22)       [snr]   {2.};   &   \node   (e23)       [stext] {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}};      \\                                                               
            \node   (e31)       {}; &   \node   (e32)       [snr]   {3.};   &   \node   (e33)       [stext] {Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteil}};                  \\
        };

    \node   [fit=(e11)(e31),label={[rotate=90,xshift=1mm]center:\textbf\tiny{Einlegen}}] {};

    \matrix (arbeitsstellung)   [below=.3cm of einlegen]
        {
            \node   (a11)       {}; &   \node   (a12)       [snr]   {4.};   & \node (a13)       [stext] {MZ 12 V\beschr{Spanner Innenblech vorw\"arts}};            \\
            \node   (a21)       {}; &   \node   (a22)       [snr]   {5.};   & \node (a23)       [stext] {M1 \& M2 V\beschr{B\"ugel M1 \& M2 vorw\"arts}};           \\
            \node   (a31)       {}; &   \node   (a32)       [snr]   {6.};   & \node (a33)       [stext] {M3 \& M6 V\beschr{B\"ugel M3 \& M6 vorw\"arts}};           \\
            \node   (a41)       {}; &   \node   (a42)       [snr]   {7.};   & \node (a43)       [stext] {M4 \& M5 V\beschr{B\"ugel M4 \& M5 vorw\"arts}};           \\
            \node   (a51)       {}; &   \node   (a52)       [snr]   {8.};   & \node (a53)       [stext] {MZ 13 V\beschr{Klemmeinheit l\"osen}}; \\                  
            \node   (a61)       {}; &   \node   (a62)       [snr]   {9.};   & \node (a63)       [stext] {MZ 14 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahme vorw\"arts}};          \\
            \node   (a71)       {}; &   \node   (a72)       [snr]   {10.};& \node   (a73)       [stext] {MZ 15-19 V\beschr{Niederhalteraufnahmen vorw\"arts}};          \\
            \node   (a81)       {}; &   \node   (a82)       [snr]   {11.};& \node   (a83)       [stext] {MZ 21-22 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}};           \\
            \node   (a91)       {}; &   \node   (a92)       [snr]   {12.};& \node   (a93)       [stext] {MZ 23-24 V\beschr{Niederhalterzustellungen vorw\"arts}};           \\
            \node   (a101)  {}; &   \node   (a102)  [snr]   {13.};& \node   (a103)  [stext] {MZ 20 V\beschr{Sperrventil vorw\"arts}};   \\
        };



\node   [fit=(a11)(a101),label={[rotate=90]center:\textbf\tiny{Falze in Arbeitsstellung}}] {};
\begin{scope}   [every path/.style=pfeil]
                \path   (e33)   --  (a13);
            \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: If you use a `matrix of nodes`, you just need to include `node text` in every position. Instead of `\node (a22) [snr] {5.};` just `5.`. With this syntax, every node is named `matrix name-row-column`. If you need to change any option can use `|[options list]| node text`...

Comment: ... You can also add `column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=base}},
column 2/.style={nodes={snr}},column 3/.style={nodes={stext}}},nodes in empty cells` to `every matrix` style. With this syntax, `einlegen` matrix could be written with `\matrix (einlegen) { & 1. & {Frg 1\beschr{Freigabe Einfahrt Bauteil}}\ & 2. & {MZ 11 V\beschr{Sauger ein}}\\ & 3. &{Frg 2\beschr{Freigabe Ausfahrt Bauteil}}\\};`

Comment: ... Vertical nodes don't need to be `labels`, regular nodes are OK. You don't need `fit` to place them because you can use any matrix internal node to place it, something like `\node   [rotate=90,] at ([ xshift=1mm]einlegen-2-1) {\textbf\tiny{Einlegen}};` could be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What happens here?

The problem here is, that the value of `text width` (which is stored in the internal macro `\tikz@text@width`) is evaluated twice for the construction of the node. First when the content of the `font` key (stored in `\tikz@textfont`) is active, and then again after the node text is collected but without `\tikz@textfont` executed:

1. Before the node text is collected in `\tikz@do@fig`:

   ```
   \tikz@textfont%
   \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty%
   \else%
     \begingroup%
       \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@text@width}%
       \pgfutil@minipage[t]{\pgf@x}\leavevmode\hbox{}%
       \tikz@text@action%
   \fi%
   ```

   The `\tikz@textfont` which contains `\tiny` does obviously change font-dependent sizes like `em` and `ex` which result in a `minipage` width of `25em =  170.14122pt`.
2. After the node text is collected and the box is created (still only `170pt` wide) there is another check in `\tikz@fig@continue`:

   ```
   \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty%
   \else%
     \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@text@width}%
     \wd\pgfnodeparttextbox=\pgf@x%
   \fi%
   ```

   You see, the same happens again but now without `\tiny` active which results in a `\pgf@x` set to around `25em = 250pt`.
   The width of the constructed box is then set to these `250pt`.
3. You have a node with a box `250pt` wide but only contents of `170pt` width.

(I consider this at least a non-feature. Why is `text width` checked again anyway?)

### Fixes

We can fix this in various ways.

#### Don’t use font-dependent dimensions …

… in `text width`, `text height` and `text depth` (the latter two won’t get executed twice like the width but you will still get results that are not in relation with the actual font-size inside the node).

With `text width=5cm` I get:

> [image]

#### Don’t use the `font` key for font-size switches.

You could just issue `\tiny` right at the start of your `tikzpicture` (but then all font-related dimensions get changed, which seems in your example only be in the `minimum height` key of the `stext` style). With `text width=25em` and `\tiny` active in the TikZ picture, I get:

> [image]

Or use it manually in the node text itself, this is most of the times not an option because it would involve more manual work which we wanted to avoid with the `font` key in the first place.

#### Only evaluate the `text width` input once.

If you insist on using font-dependent sizes you could let `text width` evaluate its content right when it is used (which means that these dimension will always be evaluated with the font-size active *outside* of the node). The fix consist of:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{text width/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1}\edef\tikz@text@width{+\pgfmathresult pt}}
\makeatother
```

With this fix and `text width=15em`, I get:

> [image]

#### Don’t let TikZ “correct” the width of the box.

With no warranty that this doesn’t break anything, we can simply remove the second check for `\tikz@text@width` from the construction code. `etoolbox` makes this very simply:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\tikz@fig@continue{\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox=\pgf@x}{}{}
\patchcmd\tikz@fig@continue{%
    \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty%
    \else%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@text@width}%
      \wd\pgfnodeparttextbox=\pgf@x%
    \fi%
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

(Same output as above.)