# change font size in rectangle node but keep node size

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, nodes

I am trying to change the font size in a rectangle node but still have the rectangle a predefined size (the one of t=other rectangles). And also, I would like to left align in some nodes, and have a line break...

I have been through many Q&A but can't make it work.

[image]

so here is the example code:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
punktchain/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
punktchain2/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
punktchain3/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.8cm]
     \node[punktchain] (x1) {TUTU};
     \node[punktchain2, below=1.5cm of x1] (x2) {TITI:\\TOTO};
     \node[punktchain2, below =1.5cm of x2] (x3) {TATA};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I would like "TITI:" to be left aligned and with sriptnotesize and "TOTO" after a line break and of scriptnotesize too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such size as scriptnotesize. You may be confusing `\scriptsize` and `\footnotesize`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Font size

If the `class=minimal` option is used with the `standalone` class, the standard font-size modifying macros (such as `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, etc.) are not available. However, if you *really* have to use that class option, you can always define those macros that you need.

The `standalone` class uses a 10pt font size by default. According to [subsection 5.2 of the LaTeX2e documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Font-sizes), when the default font size is 10pt, `\scriptsize` and `\footnotesize` are defined by `\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont` and `\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont`, respectively.

### Left alignment and line breaks in `tikz` nodes

See [this canonical answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/21891) on how to effect line breaks in `tikz` nodes. One approach is to use `align=left` and `\\`, but it seems that the font size on a given line is not affected by modifications on previous lines; this means that, with this approach, you need to modify the size of each line individually. Not very maintainable...

A better (in your case, at least) approach is to use a `tabular` composed of one left-aligned column (see below).

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\scriptsize{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont}
\def\footnotesize{\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont}

\tikzset{
punktchain/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
punktchain2/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
punktchain3/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=12em, minimum height=3em},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm]
    \node[punktchain] (x1) {TUTU};
  \node[punktchain2, below=1.5cm of x1] (x2)
  {
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        TITI:\\
        TOTO
    \end{tabular}
  };
    \node[punktchain2, below =1.5cm of x2] (x3) {TATA};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK thanks. I didn't realize that class=minimal was preventing a change in the font size. for the line break inside a node environment, thank you for the link. Since I have to use left aligned it sorts the issue pretty easily.

Comment: `font=\scriptsize, align=left` works around the ``\\`` problem. For the downsides of using `font`, see [Strech the text to the borders of a node by using \hfill](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121473) (CVS has this fixed IIRC) which is why I prefer to use either fixed units or `/utils/exec=\scriptsize` which would make the node also smaller in this case but in other cases it is IMO better (the `inner sep`s are also correctly calculated then).