# \usetikzlibrary{external} for compilation speedup incompatible with center page alignment via TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-external, animate, externalize

For larger beamer presentation I have a bunch of (TikZ) animations (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/515519/828) for a little context).
To speed up compilation, I would like to get some help from `\usetikzlibrary{external}` in my preamble.

The problem now is that I also have quite large movies (from rotating samples, the presentation is on Microtomography), which I load via `\animategraphics[every=\everyframe]{25}{frame}{000}{500}`
(I have defined a variable `\everyframe` which helps speeding up the compilation of these movies for preview purposes).
These movies are aligned on the center of the frame by encapsulating them in a centered node like so

```
\begin{frame}{Visualization}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.center){%
        \animategraphics[autoplay,palindrome,width=\paperwidth,every=\everyframe]{25}{./movies/scan/visualization/lung}{000}{473}%
        };%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
```

Now it seems to me that using `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and aligning the movies to the `current page.center` with TikZ are mutually exclusive.
If I externalize the animations, then the movies are not aligned on the center of the page.
If I don't externalize the anmimations, compiling the document takes too long to do often.

Is there a way of both having the cake and eating it, e.g. externalizing the animations and aligning the movies on the page center?

I've seen this question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150345/828) which deals with needed number of compilations, but I *think* I cannot have the animations in their separate PDF files, since they are PNG frames which get loaded with `\animagegraphics`.
This also makes it hard to provide a good MWE

BTW1: I am aware that all this is just cosmetics, a final run before standing in front of the students will take care of all this.
Nonetheless I'd really like to have a nice preview of my presenation with minimized compilation time.

BTW2: The current state of the presentation can be found [here in its GitHub repository](https://github.com/habi/lecture.microtomography).

Comment: While working on your document, you could also set option `draft`, when loading the `animate` package.

Comment: @AlexG: I know, but then I don't see *any* images, which is kind of what I want to do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While skimming through the TikZ manual section "Externalizing Graphics" I found this:

> `/tikz/external/export={boolean}` (no default, initially true)
>
> A boolean which can be used to disable the export mechanism for all
>   pictures inside of the current TeX-scope.

Thus, to exempt certain `tikzpicure` environments from externalization, such as those for page-centering the animated bitmaps, you simply need:

```
\begin{frame}{Visualization}
    {%
    \tikzset{external/export=false}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.center){%
        \animategraphics[autoplay,palindrome,width=\paperwidth,every=\everyframe]{25}{./movies/scan/visualization/lung}{000}{473}%
        };%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
\end{frame}
```

**BTW**, combining the frame option `[c]` and the `centering` environment has the similar effect of centering content both vertically and horizontally, with less effort:

```
\begin{frame}[c]{Visualization}
\begin{centering}
  \animategraphics[autoplay,palindrome,width=\paperwidth,every=\everyframe]{25}{./movies/scan/visualization/lung}{000}{473}%
  \par%
\end{centering}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I'll use the first suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: And; I'm using the TikZ-page-centering method because I want the animations centered on the whole page/frame and not only on the text area (which might actually be an issue of our university template...). See here for the BTW suggestion: https://share.getcloudapp.com/p9uz9xD8 and here for the TikZ solution: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8uwg70v