# Why the background of a pgf fitting node with minimum width equal to another (backgrounded) fitting node's width is shifted?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, backgrounds, width, pgflayers

I have two `pgf` fitting nodes:

- one below the other,
- left aligned,
- with different (unpredictable) widths,

and I'd like them be backgrounded, with backgrounds of the same width.

For this, I got help from [Creating a node fitting the horizontal width of two other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/creating-a-node-fitting-the-horizontal-width-of-two-other-nodes) but I encounter a trouble pointed out by the following MWE: the background of the second node with minimum width equal to the first one's is horizontally shifted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\ttfamily]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n11)                            {x};
  \node (n12) [right=of n11,xshift= 5mm] {x};
  \node (n21) [below=of n11,yshift=10mm] {x};
  \node (n22) [right=of n21]             {x};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[
        fill=red!20,
        inner sep=0pt,
        fit=(n11) (n12)
        ] (n1) {};
    \path let
        \p1=(n1.west),
        \p2=(n1.east)
    in node [
        fill=blue!20,
        inner sep=0pt,
        fit=(n21) (n22),
        minimum width=\x2-\x1-\pgflinewidth
        ] (n2) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: For `n2`, you may use `fit=(n21) (n22) (n1 |- n21) (n1 |- n21)` without `minimum width` (and add `line width=0` to `n1` defintion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (if I understand the question):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,backgrounds,fit}
\tikzset{
  every node/.style={font=\ttfamily}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (n11)                            {x};
  \node (n12) [right=of n11,xshift= 5mm] {x};
  \node (n21) [below=of n11,yshift=10mm] {x};
  \node (n22) [right=of n21]             {x};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [fill=red!20 ,inner sep=0pt,fit=(n11)(n12),line width=0] (n1) {};
    \node [fill=blue!20,inner sep=0pt,fit=(n21)(n22)(n1.west |-n21)(n1.east |-n22)] (n2) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAICS, you understood perfectly well and this way of doing is much more elegant! If I'm right, `(n1.west |-n21)` isn't necessary as `(n1)` and `(n2)` are left aligned, isn't it? Could you explain why `line width=0` is necessary for `(n1)` but not for `(n2)`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I must define `n1` with `line width=0` because the second `fit` operation uses `n1`. Try `line width=1cm` to see the difference.