# TikZ: Get width of node that shouln't be drawn

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a node A that has the same width as a node B. But node B should not be drawn. How can I get B's width?

Answer (score 2):

This is in part based on [Creating a node fitting the horizontal width of two other nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23480/creating-a-node-fitting-the-horizontal-width-of-two-other-nodes)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw = none] at (0,-1) (B) {\phantom{This node should be hidden}};
\path let \p1=($(B.west)-(B.east)$),
    \n1 = {veclen(\p1)-\pgflinewidth}
    in node[minimum width=\n1,draw] at (0,-1) (A) {foobar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also create a phantom node by just setting `opacity=0` (which will affect border, fill, and text).

Comment: Using opacity=0 still leaves the text selectable, though.

Comment: As I understand it, the node will be drawn in the end. Hence, the text's being selectable doesn't seem to be an issue in this case.

Comment: In my use case I generate the LaTeX code in Matlab. I need the width of a node that will be added to the .tex file later and at a yet unknown position (due to relative positioning). But I think this less specific question & answer is more useful. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: If you don't have any funky text (math stuff or font switches) you can go about it with `\node[minimum width={width("This node should be hidden")},draw] at (0,-1) (A) {foobar};`

Comment: In some cases that could be a solution, but I need A's and B's (if it were displayed) frame to have the same width.

Comment: Your edit means my answer no longer makes sense. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I don't know what *A's and B's* refer to.

Answer (score 1):

> ***This answer addresses the original question before it was edited in a
>   way which renders this answer inapplicable.***

*Of course, you could never draw the saved node, but that would be an unnecessarily circuitous route.*

It is possible to save a constructed node and draw it later. This means that you can save the node, measure it, use the result to do something else and then draw the original node.

The basic method is demonstrated on page 1030 of the Ti*k*Z manual in the PGF section. I define some additional convenience commands which let us write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mylaternode [fill=magenta, blend mode=normal, draw=magenta, fill opacity=.5, draw opacity=.75] (hi) {Hello world};
```

`\mylaternode` should hopefully work just like `\node` except that we should not position it i.e. we don't want an `at` or anything. This commands makes available `\mylaternodewidth` which stores the width of the node less the current line width. This is correct if the nodes are drawn. If not, you would need to adjust the definition or manually add the width back in.

We can now use this to construct another node of matching width.

```
  \node [top color=blue!50!cyan, bottom color=blue!50!cyan, middle color=white, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=\mylaternodewidth, draw=blue!50!cyan] at (10mm,10mm) {};
```

Finally, we use `\placemynode(<x>,<y>)` to actually draw the saved node.

```
  \placemynode(10mm,10mm)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Finishing the picture, we get the following result.

[image: hello world! (later)]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
% adapted from manual 1030
\newbox\mybox
\newcommand*\mysaver{%
  \global\setbox\mybox=\box\pgfpositionnodelaterbox
  \global\let\myname=\pgfpositionnodelatername
  \global\let\myminx=\pgfpositionnodelaterminx
  \global\let\myminy=\pgfpositionnodelaterminy
  \global\let\mymaxx=\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
  \global\let\mymaxy=\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\mylaternodexlength{abs(\mymaxx-\myminx)-\pgflinewidth}%
  \global\let\mylaternodewidth=\mylaternodexlength
}
\newcommand*\myrestorer{%
  \let\pgfpositionnodelatername=\myname
  \let\pgfpositionnodelaterminx=\myminx
  \let\pgfpositionnodelaterminy=\myminy
  \let\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx=\mymaxx
  \let\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy=\mymaxy
  \setbox\pgfpositionnodelaterbox=\box\mybox
}
\def\mylaternode#1;{%
  {%
    \pgfpositionnodelater{\mysaver}
    \node #1;
  }%
}
\def\placemynode(#1,#2){%
  \myrestorer
  \pgfpositionnodenow{\pgfqpoint{#1}{#2}}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mylaternode [fill=magenta, blend mode=normal, draw=magenta, fill opacity=.5, draw opacity=.75] (hi) {Hello world};
  \node [top color=blue!50!cyan, bottom color=blue!50!cyan, middle color=white, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=\mylaternodewidth, draw=blue!50!cyan] at (10mm,10mm) {};
  \placemynode(10mm,10mm)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me if the picture displays correctly? Firefox has decided that the image hosting site is not safe so I cannot tell.

Comment: Chrome displays the same error

Comment: @AlexanderWilms I re-uploaded it, but it makes no difference.