# How to programmatically find the height and width of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I programmatically find the height and width of a node?

```
\usepackage{twemojis}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{nodestyle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, thick, fill=black!50}}
    \node[nodestyle] (node00) at (0, 0) {{\LARGE\texttwemoji{dollar banknote}}};
    \node[nodestyle, right=0pt of node00] (node01) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to set the height and width `node01` identical to `node00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\pgfgetlastxy` or `\pgfextractx` and `\pgfextracty`.  One uses macros and the other uses length registers.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{twemojis}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}

\newcommand{\getwh}[1]{% #1 = node name (no parens)
  \pgfextractx{\mywidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{east}}}%
  \pgfextracty{\myheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{north}}}%
}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{nodestyle/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, thick, fill=black!50}}
    \node[nodestyle] (node00) at (0, 0) {{\LARGE\texttwemoji{dollar banknote}}};
    \getwh{node00}% get size based on anchors
    \addtolength{\mywidth}{-0.8pt}% remove line thickness
    \addtolength{\myheight}{-0.8pt}% remove line thickness
    \node[nodestyle, right=0pt, minimum width=\mywidth, minimum height=\myheight] at (node00.east) (node01) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes node01 bigger than node00 since node00's anchors include the outer seps while the outer seps are added to the minimum widths and heights specified for node01.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - Close, but it is not due to inner sep or rounded corners, but the line thickness.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested by this solution that computes it by computing the distance between the north/east anchors, subtracting the width of the line, directly using standard operations on paths:

[TikZ: Get width of node that shouln't be drawn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336257/tikz-get-width-of-node-that-shoulnt-be-drawn)

Comment: Ah yes, `\pgflinewidth`!  Except in this case it is `2\pgflinewidth`.